# Imgur 401 when trying to upload to imgur

Tags: c#, imgur

I'm making a snipping tool that can quickly upload to imgur.
But when I'm uploading the image, it gives me a 401 error.

Picture_Viewer.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Extensions;
using System.Web.Script;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Snipping_Tool
{
    public partial class Picture_Viewer : Form
    {


    public Picture_Viewer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    int selectX;
    int selectY;
    int selectWidth;
    int selectHeight;
    public Pen selectPen;
    bool start = false;

    const string ClientId = "client_id";
    const string ClientSecret = "client_secret"; //I have it registered but I don't want to show it. Sorry!



    private void Picture_Viewer_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (pictureBox1.Image == null)
            return;
        //validate if right-click was trigger
        if (start)
        {
            //refresh picture box
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
            //set corner square to mouse coordinates
            selectWidth = e.X - selectX;
            selectHeight = e.Y - selectY;
            //draw dotted rectangle
            pictureBox1.CreateGraphics().DrawRectangle(selectPen,
                      selectX, selectY, selectWidth, selectHeight);
        }
    }

    private void Picture_Viewer_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!start)
        {
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                //starts coordinates for rectangle
                selectX = e.X;
                selectY = e.Y;
                selectPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 1);
                selectPen.DashStyle = DashStyle.DashDotDot;
            }
            //refresh picture box
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
            //start control variable for draw rectangle
            start = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //validate if there is image
            if (pictureBox1.Image == null)
                return;
            //same functionality when mouse is over
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                pictureBox1.Refresh();
                selectWidth = e.X - selectX;
                selectHeight = e.Y - selectY;
                pictureBox1.CreateGraphics().DrawRectangle(selectPen, selectX,
                         selectY, selectWidth, selectHeight);

            }
            start = false;
            //function save image to clipboard
        }
    }



    private void SaveToClipboard()
    {
        //validate if something selected
        if (selectWidth > 0)
        {

            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(selectX, selectY, selectWidth, selectHeight);
            //create bitmap with original dimensions
            Bitmap OriginalImage = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
            //create bitmap with selected dimensions
            Bitmap _img = new Bitmap(selectWidth, selectHeight);
            //create graphic variable
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(_img);
            //set graphic attributes
            g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            g.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            g.DrawImage(OriginalImage, 0, 0, rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            //insert image stream into clipboard
            Clipboard.SetImage(_img);
        }
        else
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, pictureBox1.Image.Width, pictureBox1.Image.Height);
            Bitmap OriginalImage = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
            //create bitmap with selected dimensions
            Bitmap _img = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image.Width, pictureBox1.Image.Height);
            //create graphic variable
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(_img);
            //set graphic attributes
            g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            g.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            g.DrawImage(OriginalImage, 0, 0, rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            Clipboard.SetImage(_img);
        }
        this.Close();
    }

    private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void Picture_Viewer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void copyToClipboardCTRLCToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SaveToClipboard();
    }

    public Bitmap _img;
    private void uploadToImgurToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (selectWidth > 0)
        {

            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(selectX, selectY, selectWidth, selectHeight);
            //create bitmap with original dimensions
            Bitmap OriginalImage = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
            //create bitmap with selected dimensions
            Bitmap _img = new Bitmap(selectWidth, selectHeight);
            //create graphic variable
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(_img);
            //set graphic attributes
            g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            g.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            g.DrawImage(OriginalImage, 0, 0, rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            //insert image stream into clipboard
            _img.Save(@"C:\Users\Public\Documents\snap.png", ImageFormat.Png);
        }
        else
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, pictureBox1.Image.Width, pictureBox1.Image.Height);
            Bitmap OriginalImage = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
            //create bitmap with selected dimensions
            Bitmap _img = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image.Width, pictureBox1.Image.Height);
            //create graphic variable
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(_img);
            //set graphic attributes
            g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            g.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            g.DrawImage(OriginalImage, 0, 0, rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            _img.Save(@"C:\Users\Public\Documents\snap.png", ImageFormat.Png);
        }

        PostToImgur(@"C:\Users\Public\Documents\snap.png", ClientId, ClientSecret);

    }

    public void PostToImgur(string imagFilePath, string apiKey, string apiSecret)
    {
        byte[] imageData;

        FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(imagFilePath);
        imageData = new byte[fileStream.Length];
        fileStream.Read(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
        fileStream.Close();

        const int MAX_URI_LENGTH = 32766;
        string base64img = System.Convert.ToBase64String(imageData);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < base64img.Length; i += MAX_URI_LENGTH)
        {
            sb.Append(Uri.EscapeDataString(base64img.Substring(i, Math.Min(MAX_URI_LENGTH, base64img.Length - i))));
        }

        string uploadRequestString = "client_id" + apiKey + "client_secret" + apiSecret + "&title=" + "imageTitle" +
            "&caption=" + "img" + "&image=" + sb.ToString();

        // strin

        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.imgur.com/3/upload.json");
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;

        StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
        streamWriter.Write(uploadRequestString);
        streamWriter.Close();

        WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse(); //401 ERROR
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

        string responseString = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        this.Close();
    }

}
```

}

It includes other codes though so it won't work when you try to test it.
The error is not in that code, it's really in this.
I have the application registered with the API, I have read some Documentary but no where stands where the problem really is. Not even on Google or here..
Thanks in advance :).

**EDIT:**

Did something with Fiddler but I have no idea how to use it.
Here is what the api send (in raw):

```
CONNECT api.imgur.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: api.imgur.com
Connection: Keep-Alive

A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.

Version: 3.1 (TLS/1.0)
Random: 52 A8 84 03 80 45 BC AC 57 7A 4B B9 19 88 79 8B 94 A5 43 8A F8 0F 51 4B 07 E1 F8 11 96 33 E1 55
SessionID: empty
Extensions: 
    renegotiation_info  00
    server_name api.imgur.com
    elliptic_curves secp256r1 [0x17], secp384r1 [0x18]
    ec_point_formats    uncompressed [0x0]
    SessionTicket TLS   empty
Ciphers: 
    [002F]  TLS_RSA_AES_128_SHA
    [0035]  TLS_RSA_AES_256_SHA
    [0005]  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
    [000A]  SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
    [C013]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [C014]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [C009]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [C00A]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [0032]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_SHA
    [0038]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_SHA
    [0013]  SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
    [0004]  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5

Compression: 
    [00]    NO_COMPRESSION
```

Comment: 401 is unauthorized, how confident are you that apiKey and apiSecret are valid?

Comment: I'm really confident, it's even like that on the Imgur website and the email I got from them.

Comment: Run Fiddler and paste what is being sent by this and by original website - that should tell (cookies, hidden fields etc)

Comment: in XML or...? because the XML is empty. (it didn't send any cookies)

Comment: Raw is perfectly fine

Comment: edited in in. Have a look :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the imgur API docs, and your code, it would appear you are not sending a required header: `Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN`. Without this token, your request will be 401.

> Finally, after obtaining your access_token, you make your API requests
>   by sending the Authorization header as such:
>
> Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

Source: https://api.imgur.com/oauth2

Edit as per your comment: to set the auth header in C#, simply add the following line of code when you are preparing your httpwebrequest:

`request.Headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN;`

Comment: I don't know how to use it. I barely figured out how to do this. I will screw around with it though and see what I can do.

Comment: Thank you, but.. The name 'request' does not exist in the current context

Comment: definition for 'request' and no extension method 'request' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?.     I'm missing an assembly reference?

Comment: @Stepepper I was referring to the `webRequest` variable you are working with.

Comment: I did that, only I get 2 errors of 'Too many characters in literal' and one error of 'The name 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN' does not exist in current context'

Comment: Do I need to put my key in place of YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN?

Comment: Yes, that's a placeholder. You'll see that type of thing in code snippets a lot. Also, it's not your api key, it's the token you receive from imgur after you authenticate.

Comment: Stuck here.. don't know what to do then.

Comment: @Stepepper it would seem that, since you aren't fully familiar with C# or APIs, that you should use one of the many python or ruby libraries available to upload things to imgur. It would take longer to explain all the idiosyncrasies and nuance of getting this to work than it would take you to figure out how to use a readily available tool.

Comment: Could you send me a python library for uploading to imgur :)?

Comment: @Stepepper are you proficient with Python? If you aren't there really is no point as you will struggle to get things working. The whole point is that you need to be proficient in a language before you start trying to interact with web APIs.

Comment: Well, don't call me proficient, but I have some experience in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Without Fiddler logs it's really guessing, so here goes:

```
"client_id" + apiKey + "client_secret" + apiSecret + "&title=" + "imageTitle" ...
```

Looks like you're missing two '='s and one '&'. Try:

```
"client_id=" + apiKey + "&client_secret=" + apiSecret + "&title=" + "imageTitle" ...
```

Comment: I'm missing a '&' at the imagetitle? And where to I miss the '='s?

Comment: Keep it there, rdodev's answer is probably the core issue but you will need this too.

Comment: yes, this part is probably needed as well. OP is probably a novice and this sort of thing tend to get messy.